# regex to unmatch the white space or empty tag or the $ symbol

Tags: regex, xsd

I was writing the regex in the XSD for one of the XML element.
The conditions are below:
It shouldn't be empty or white space or the tag value should not contain the $ followed by an alphabets.
    Example:

```
<element>I am $A test</element>--- this is invalid.

<element>I am $a test</element>--- this is invalid.

<element></element>--- this is invalid.
<element>   </element>--- this is invalid.

<element>I am $123.0 test on 02/01/2018 ongoing </element>--- this is valid.
<element>I am $123.0 test on 02/01/2018 ongoing 
month for another year
</element>--- this is valid.
<element>I am test</element>--- this is valid.
```

For checking the empty/blank spaces I am using below regex.
but this would not work for $ character followed by an alphabet.
XSD:

```
<xs:element name="element" minOccurs="1">
<xs:simpleType>
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:minLength value="1" />
<xs:pattern value="[\s\S]*[^ ][\s\S]*" />
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Can you please help me with the above problem.

Comment: This works with most engines `(?s)^(?!.*\$[a-zA-Z])(?!\s*$).*$`

Comment: @sln XSD regex engine is a text-directed one and does not support lookarounds.

Comment: Oh, what exact engine is it ?

Comment: @sln XML Schema regex engine.

Comment: Then, the closest you can get is `^[^$\s]*((?:\s*\$\d[^$\s]*|\s+[^$\s]*)*)$` Where it will not check for the empty element. So, no empty element check is going to be available ... sorry

Comment: @sln Xsd regex does not support anchors thus the caret and dollar symbols will be treated as literal chars.  Also, noncapturing groups are not supported.

Comment: Oh, this looks to be a final solution, which does it all `([^$\s]*(\s*$\d[^$\s]*|\s+[^$\s]+)+|[^$\s]+(\s*$\d[^$\s]*|\s+[^$\s]*)*)`

Comment: Probably a normal equivalent regex without assertions would be `^(?:[^$\s]*(?:\s*\$\d[^$\s]*|\s+[^$\s]+)+|[^$\s]+(?:\s*\$\d[^$\s]*|\s+[^$\s]*)*)$` that you could try on a regex test site.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew- it didn't work for $ followed by an alphabets set, its passing all the cases.

Comment: @sln -Thank you so much :) your second last solution worked for me. Appreciate your help :)

Comment: @Manoj, I see, I had no chance to test it. sln's regex matches non-empty strings that do not contain `$` or that contain `$` followed with a digit. So, that regex does not match `I am $-123.0 test` string. Probably you may fix it by replacing `\d` with `[^a-zA-Z]` or `\P{L}`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew- it worked :) , thanks for your effort (Y) .

Comment: @sln- its not passing below scenario:
<element>I am $123.0 test on 02/01/2018 ongoing 
month for another year
</element>--- this is valid.
Could you please help